# Unplugged while resizing partition - now get GRUB rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, disk, drive

So today I was trying to expand my Xenial disk par. I accidentally kicked my power extension, and it unplugged the computer while it was working. My computer lost power at about 30 percent of the way through. When I tried to boot it up again, it said

```
error: invalid arch-independent ELF magic
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Most likely the data is lost.

Comment: @Pilot6 Please tell me the **good news**.

Comment: You can try testdisk from Ubuntu LiveCD and try to pull out some of your data. It is better than nothing.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok, i'll try... to try

Comment: Install testdisk and use it. you can easily find guides how to use testdisk, if you try to search.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok. I did it successfully! Good thing i backed up my data on sda2. I will just have to reinstall on sda6 (the original broken par.) Thanks!!! :D